# Redraw a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uiview

I need to literally redraw a UITableView upon an event in my code.  But everything I've tryed doesn't seem to work.  I've tried `[self.tableView reloadData]`,  I've played with the delegates.  The goal I'm trying to achieve is to render a completely different UITableView, with differently formatted cells.  So I need to redraw the table.  Any help would be appreciated.

Heres my code:

```
       ...
    if/else...
    }
    //Now I want to reload the tableView
    [tableView reloadData];    //Isn't getting it done
    NSLog(@"index = %i", index);  //Always fires
    tableView.delegate = self;  // Didn't help
    [tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];  // Also nothing
}
```

The point of what I'm trying to do is this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
         if (segmentOptions == snacks) {
             cell = [[TableViewCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
              NSLog(@"A");
         } else {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            NSLog(@"B");
         }
     }
  ...
}
```

Comment: if you're using the same datasource and delegate why doesn't reload data work? it should totally relayout the cells, recreating them from the delegate and datasource completely

Comment: have you debugged the code, whether after reloading of data what is happening inside delegate and datasource methods.

Comment: Some points to check: Are you sure your event is fired ? Did you use some `NSLog` or debug to verify ? Where do you use `reloadData` ? It should work. Could you post some code ?
Have you checked if `self.tableview` is `nil` ? Btw, do you want to redraw your `UITableView` or refresh the data displayed inside of it ?

Comment: 1. I'm absolutly sure the event is firing.  It trigers a Log every time.

Comment: 2. I used `reloadData` right after the code updates with the new info

Comment: 3. The tableView is not nil, because I don't set it to nil, and it is on screen.  So I assume it wouldn't randomly go to nil

Comment: What does your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` look like?

Comment: I want to construct completely different looking cells, so I need to redraw, not just update the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You possibly meant something like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell-not-snacks";

    if (segmentOptions == snacks) {
        cellIdentifier = @"cell-snacks";
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
         if (segmentOptions == snacks) {
             cell = [[TableViewCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
         } else {
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be worth looking at the method [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) in the [UITableViewCell Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell). This method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:.

You can override this method on your custom UITableViewCell (do not forget including [super prepareForReuse]) in order to redraw whatever you need to redraw.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is: `if (cell == nil) {`.  I removed that and it works perfectly every time.

Comment: If you do this then you are not taking advantage of cell reuse which makes your tables more efficient. I would suggest you carry on looking into the proper solution of you will likely be bitten later (maybe on a different app if you don't understand what this is doing)

Comment: @Paul.s is right, this is probably hides the probleme. Also, you look like you have at least two different types of cell (snacks and not snacks)

Comment: Thomas, Thats correct.  Im willing to take a different solution, this is just the only one that works at the moment.  I think I understand why this is bad, but it is my only solution at the moment.  I need a way to draw the cells as type A or type B

Comment: So i guess you want to reload new cells when your segmentOption changes ? if so you have to extend your if to something like if(cell == nil || forceReloadCells) and simply update the value of forceReloadCells to YES when your event is triggered. forceReloadCells can be a private attribute of your class.